# Access Pi 4 which is using a VPN over SSH?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn

So I want to run a VPN on my Pi4, but when I do, I cant ssh from my Desktop Pc! I read something about making an ip route but I have no idea how that works...

I am using NordVpn btw.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution:

```
nordvpn whitelist add port 22
```